# Signing off my website but not facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

As the title says is there a way to make a user log out of my website instead of logging out of my website and facebook? Currently I'm using

```
<a href="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href" id="log_out" onclick="FB.logout();">Log out</a>
```

Comment: That depends on how you're handling Facebook authentication on your site.  If Facebook data is the only way, then no there isn't a way to do this.

Comment: From the [developer documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.1): *"Note: This function call will also log the person out of Facebook. The reason for this is that someone may have logged into your app and into Facebook during the login flow. If this is the case, they might not expect to still be logged into Facebook when they log out of your app. To avoid confusing people and to protect personal security, we enforce this logout behavior."*

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `FB.logout()` ---

Just clear whatever data you're using of facebook's -

i.e. :

```
delete objThatHoldsTheUsersData;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you some ideas:

- [Facebook API Logout of my app but not facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189386/facebook-api-logout-of-my-app-but-not-facebook)
- [How to log out user from facebook application, but maintain login from facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783751/how-to-log-out-user-from-facebook-application-but-maintain-login-from-facebook)
- [How do I log a user out of my FB app but not Facebook site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425595/how-do-i-log-a-user-out-of-my-fb-app-but-not-facebook-site)